# Change Azure website app settings from code

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, appsettings

Is it possible to change the app settings for a website from the app itself?

This is not meant to be an everyday operation, but a self-service reconfiguration option. A non-developer can change a specific setting, which should cause a restart, just like I can do manually on the website configuration page (app setting section)

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the Azure Fluent Api.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
```

...

```cs
public void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    string tenantId = "a5fd91ad-....-....-....-............";
    string clientSecret = "8a9mSPas....................................=";
    string clientId = "3030efa6-....-....-....-............";
    string subscriptionId = "a4a5aff6-....-....-....-............";

    var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(new
      ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret
    }, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

    var _azure = Azure
   .Configure()
   .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
   .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
   .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

    var appResourceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxx"; //Get From WebApp -> Properties -> Resource ID

    var webapp = _azure.WebApps.GetById(appResourceId);

    //Set App Setting Key and Value
    webapp.Update()
        .WithAppSetting(key, value)
        .Apply();
}
```

Comment: I got compile time error on line `var _azure = Azure.Configure()...` `Azure` not found, Do I need to install any other nuget packages to resolve it?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything other than the references I typed above.

Comment: Might need to fully qualify the name Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure

Comment: Plus I needed to install nuGet packages Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent and
Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent (for app services)

Answer (score 10):

It wasn't that hard once I found the right lib to do it, [Microsoft Azure Web Sites Management Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites).

```cs
var credentials = GetCredentials(/*using certificate*/);
using (var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(credentials))
{
    var currentConfig = await client.WebSites.GetConfigurationAsync(webSpaceName,
                                                                    webSiteName);
    var newConfig = new WebSiteUpdateConfigurationParameters
                    {
                        ConnectionStrings = null,
                        DefaultDocuments = null,
                        HandlerMappings = null,
                        Metadata = null,
                        AppSettings = currentConfig.AppSettings
    };
    newConfig.AppSettings[mySetting] = newValue;
    await client.WebSites.UpdateConfigurationAsync(webSpaceName, webSiteName,
                                                   newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide me from where I can get `webSpaceName` and `webSiteName` from the azure portal?

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon, do you know if we would be able to update the "General Settings" to Java.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read into the [Service Management REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx)? The documentation mentions that it allows you to perform most the actions that are available via the Management Portal programmatically.

Comment: That, however, helped me get to the management libraries, which I'm now checking out

Comment: It looks like this is now supported on the REST API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Diego answer, to use the Azure Management Librairies within a WebApp (WebSites  and/or WebJobs), you need to configure SSL which is a little bit tricky:

[Using Azure Management Libraries from Azure Web Jobs](http://blog.lytzen.name/2015/07/using-azure-management-libraries-from.html)