# Programmatically start an Azure website slot

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to programmatically start a slot for an Azure website using a C# code sequence.
I've tried to use the following code:

```
public async Task StartWebsiteSlot()
{
   var subscriptionId = "{my Azure subscription id}";
   var certPath = "{my full path to the Azure management certificate}";
   var certificate = new X509Certificate2( certPath, {my password});

   var httpHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
   httpHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
   httpHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

   var url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{groupname}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{site name}/start?api-version=2015-08-01";
   var postContent = new StringContent( String.Empty );

   using (var client = new HttpClient(httpHandler))
   {
      var response = await client.PostAsync(url, postContent);
   }
 }
```

The call returns "Unathorized".
I know the certificate is ok because I'm using it with the WebManagementClient to swap deployment slots.

How should I access that specific Azure management REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Ebbo has a solution for this at https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/
One has to replace the RestartAsync call with StartSiteAsync or StartSiteSlotAsync.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/) Nuget package lets you manage the websites from C#. Once you get the nuget package loaded, you can use the [RestartAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites.iwebsiteoperations.restartasync(v=azure.11).aspx) method to start the website. See below for the usage.

```
yourwebsiteclient.Websites.RestartAsync
```

Hope this helps!

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites.iwebsiteoperations.restartasync(v=azure.11).aspx

Comment: RestartAsync does not work for me, I've tried it before asking this question (it's the reason I've tried to directly access the Azure Management REST API). Do you have a working code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question : 
[Change Azure website app settings from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874503/change-azure-website-app-settings-from-code/).

It used the Azure Management Libraries as suggested by neolursa.

The tricky part is to configure SSL : [Using Azure Management Libraries from Azure Web Jobs](http://blog.lytzen.name/2015/07/using-azure-management-libraries-from.html)