# VSO CI - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Production no matter what I do

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm creating my CI pipeline in VSO and I have .net core app, I created endpoint which says to me which value was used during publishing, exposing `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` through the API, no matter what I do, it's set to `Produciton` . My app is hosted in Azure.

The steps I did -

I looked into Azure App Service 's application settings, looking for environment. Thinking that might overwrite my variable in Release configuration.

I set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable on variables tab in release configuration, also I set it on specific environment.

setting it on environment:
[image]
[image]

setting it on release configuration:
[image]

And I'm also ruining the command `setx` with parameter `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Test"`.

[image: setx command]

None of the above seems to make any difference, when I query my endpoint I got back I'm running  on `Production` environment. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you configure .net core project to publish according to the environment? As far as I know it is used for running time.

Comment: Do you mean set environment when deploy to azure web app?

Comment: I have appsettings.json, appsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Test.json , based on IHostingEnvironment which is being passed to startup class I load additional configuration specific for an environment.

Comment: What I understood, VSO continuous deployment would set this based on what I passed to the CD pipeline, hence my images atop, however it doesn't seems to take any effect.

Comment: So, you check the value at the runtime after deploying app to azure? If so, then it check the environment of web app server. The variables in build/release are being add to environment temperate of build server for build/release lifecycle. Am I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, I load the configuration at the startup of the app.

Comment: So, you need set environment variable for web app in azure instead in build server.

Comment: You can configure environment variable in azure portal, check my update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding variable of build or release, it just affect build server. You need set environment variable for web app in azure instead in build server.

You can configure environment variable in azure portal: Select your App Service> Application Settings> Add ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT key to App Settings and set a value (e.g. Development)

On the other hand, there is a thread about update app settings programing that may benefit you: [Change Azure website app settings from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874503/change-azure-website-app-settings-from-code)

Comment: thank you alot for this explanation. Afterwards it's clear that the variables just are for each "stage" and the server in azure is different from the release stage machine. thank you!

Comment: I think setting up variable in release is great but if you are running test script with build then we have to setup on build too.