# How Do I Run EF Core Migrations with VSTS Deployment to Azure for Web API Project

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core

My project was created via `dotnet new webapi --name=ProjectName`. I've setup a build definition in VSTS. The Deployment to Azure runs fine, but I can't figure out how to run my migrations, i.e., `dotnet ef database update`

I've reviewed several of the other Stack Overflow questions. Though helpful, none of them provided a *current* solution. References:

- [Ef core migrations in full .net project in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755768/ef-core-migrations-in-full-net-project-in-vsts)
- [Run EF migration on VSTS release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957938/run-ef-migration-on-vsts-release)
- [VSO CI - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Production no matter what I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690138/vso-ci-aspnetcore-environment-is-set-to-production-no-matter-what-i-do)

The closest I've come to being successful is adding tasks like so:

- Replace Tokens: Update Connection String
- Command Line: set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
- Command Line: dotnet ef database update -v

This *almost* works, but for some reason ef still targets development.

Any recent solutions?

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log) Try to add variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and specify Production value then try again.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT. Awesome! Adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to my variables worked. I had also looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690138/vso-ci-aspnetcore-environment-is-set-to-production-no-matter-what-i-do which led me to believe that your recommendation wouldn't work, but I was pleasantly surprised. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I post an answer that you can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). On the other hand, another thread's issue is different, it runs the app on azure but you call dotnet ef command during build/release that the environment is on build/release agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to build/release definition and specify `Production` value.