# Programmatically change cron expression on pre-compiled Azure Function C#

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a pre-compiled Azure timer function deployed to a function app. In order to change the cron expression currently I need redeploy from Visual Studio.

Is there a webservice or something that I can use to programmatically change this without having to do a full redeploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the cron expression to configuration. Use `%` in attribute parameter:

```cs
[TimerTrigger("%schedule%")] TimerInfo timer
```

And define the setting `schedule` in your App settings (or in `local.settings.json` for local development).

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for the useful information - it will prevent having to redeploy from VS. Editing the App Settings still requires a manual intervention though, any idea about being able to programatically change it?

Comment: You should be able to do it via C# SDK or Powershell, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874503/change-azure-website-app-settings-from-code) for example