# Azure Web Job Timer trigger not firing when adding custom schedule to it

Tags: azure, crontrigger, webjob

I have created a function which is triggered by a timer. It runs fine when triggered from the Azure portal by clicking on the Run option on the exact time provided through the database. But does not fire automatically for the scheduled date taken from a database. The timer schedule here is not static but the value is taken from the database and converted to CRON expression. Used INameResolver to resolve the name and overwrite it with the database date and time by converting it to CRON expression.

It runs fine when a constant CRON expression is passed to TimerTrigger attribute.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about Azure Functions or Azure WebJobs? also posting the relevant code would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is a doc about this: [Dynamic update of Azure Web Job time schedule](http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com/2017/08/dynamic-update-of-azure-web-job-time.html).

It uses `NameResolver` to get dynamic bindings from AppSettings, for more details you could refer to this: [Custom binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#custom-binding-expressions).

So you could set dynamic `%TriggerSchedule%` to AppSettings with code like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877342/10383250). Then combine the webjob Function code.