# Update TimeTrigger expression dynamically Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The user inputs the CRON expression from an interface. The function app should update the appsettings to reflect the user input.

My current approach

The TimerTrigger function with `schedule` appsetting

```
    [FunctionName("Cleanup")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%schedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        // Get the connection string from app settings and use it to create a connection.
        var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("db_connection");
        log.LogInformation($"db_connection : {str}");
    }
```

Setting the `schedule` appsetting via environment variable

```
    [FunctionName("SetConfig")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SetConfig([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req)
    {
        HistoryLogDeleteConfigDto data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<HistoryLogDeleteConfigDto>();
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("schedule", data.Schedule);

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

local.settings.json file

```
"Values": {
"db_connection": "Server=DESKTOP-DFJ3PBT;Database=CovalentLogger;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
"schedule": "*/20 * * * * *"
}
```

POSTMAN request body to update the `schedule` appsetting

```
{
"Schedule": "*/30 * * * * *"
}
```

But no luck. After sending the request from postman to update the setting, if I access the azure portal function app setting I still can see the old value.

But if I query the environmnet variable like below
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("schedule", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)`
I can see the new expression. But in Azure portal function appsetting it stills the old value. So the job still executes based on the old schedule.

Where have I gone wrong? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think updating the Environment variable like that will work as the the schedule is only being read at the initialization of the Function - or when the app setting is updated on the app service. However, it should still be fairly doable. This does basically exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116234/1537195

Just package this in your HTTP-triggered Function (and I'd probably use [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity)) and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I went with this and all is working. The only problem is Azure takes minutes to update the appsettings. Even-though it might be because of the restart of the application with the update of appsettings, I feel like it is too much time for a user to wait.

Comment: Hm usually this shouldn’t take minutes in my experience. Is your function rather big (many different functions in it)? You could try to carve out the schedule-updater into a completely separate Function

Comment: Omg yes you have a point. I have 3 functions in the same place. Could that be a case then?

Comment: Hard to tell from the outside. Generally three don’t sound like a lot. But as you updater function basically needs to restart itself.

Comment: Thanks! I will make the scheduler function separate and see whether there is an improvement.