# Update app setting in Azure Function using ARM API

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to update an app setting in azure function in runtime. So far the only way i found to update is through the ARM API. Is there any other way to update app settings in azure functions ? 
Also im using postman to try out the ARM API calls. How can we configure authentication in PostMan to access ARM API

Comment: why dont you do with CI CD?

Comment: I want to do it in run-time. Basically the need is to disable the function in case of an exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the REST API:[Update Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appse) to update the settings, remember before updating the settings use the [list settings api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings) to get the existing settings, cause the update api actually is used to replace all the application settings of an app.

Except this, you could also try the Azure Cli:[az webapp config appsettings set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set) and Powershell:[Set-AzureRmWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebapp), you could use these to update or add settings, this won't replace all settings.

Comment: the [Update Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appse) gives a 404. anyway I want to update app settings programmatically. so isn't it easier to use the Rest API ?

Comment: Sorry the link miss some parameters, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings). And if you want to update it with code one way is call the REST API and other way you could refer to this [question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874503/change-azure-website-app-settings-from-code).

Comment: The [blog post](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/) really helped to get better understanding about the rest api. But i used the Azure Fluent Api approach in this [question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874503/change-azure-website-app-settings-from-code) thank you @George Chen

Answer (score 1):

There's an [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-postman) covering that and a [blog post](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/) going through that in detail

But you might want to look at the ARM Templates or Azure Cli\Powershell for that.

Comment: Thank You. I found the blog post. Im following it.